# file not found exception was unhandled on crystal report migrating from vs2008 to vs2012 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am trying to open VS2008 version application in VS2012, while running the application where it has to generate crytal report it gives an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I can see the crystal report its fine.
I already made changes in appconfig file :

```
<configuration>
  <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>    
</startup></configuration>
```

So please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify all of your app.config.(if more than one)

**Before**

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>    
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**After**

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>    
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct version of Crystal Runtime for .NET Framework or VS 2012 on your machine or your server where you are testing your app. Simply changing the configuration will not help. You can download latest runtime for VS here: [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio: Updates & Runtime Downloads](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Comment: I have crystal report for VS2012 , I have developed other app using it and it works fine.